# Flutter generates multiple .xcconfig files in background how to fix it?

Tags: flutter, generated, xcconfig

I'm building a flutter app and recently when i did git status I got this https://prnt.sc/t5moij
I'm not sure why is this happening and how to solve it since I think it behaves like a trojan virus more or less...

Any advice is appreciated.